# Converted Web Site Project to Web Application Project - Can not access UI Controls

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uicontrol, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I have converted a large project, currently in VS 2012 from a Web Site project to a Web Application project.

I have added the namespace to all of my .cs files.

I have ran the "Convert to web application" on the project and it has generated all of the needed files.  (So I do have the designer files created as part of this upgrade)

When I compile, it errors off on all of the references in my C# code behind file for all of the UI Controls.  The error indicates that the control does not exist.  The controls are there, and they are present in the designer files.

I have cleaned my solution and no matter what I do I get this error.

Any ideas / suggestions of things to try?  Have I missed something in the conversion to a Web Application?

Comment: Still can not figure this out...  Just wanted to add that I deleted all of the designer files and literally went to each ASPX page, did a right mouse click, selected "Convert To Web Application" so that it would re-generate the designer files.  I did this to almost 500 ASPX pages.  It recreated the designer files and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Fixed My Issue..   It was the inherits statement in the ASPX.  I had to include the namespace along with that...  Problem solved...

Answer (score 2):

Fixed My Issue.. It was the inherits statement in the ASPX. I had to include the namespace along with that... Problem solved...   so, the syntax is inherits="namespace.formname"